# Attribute access in Python: first slots, then __dict__?

Tags: python, attributes, slots

In the example below, attribute `x` is accessed from the slots of the object even though `x` is present in `__dict__` (this is not a typical or probably useful case, but I'm curious):

```
>>> class C(object):
...     __slots__ = 'x'
...     
>>> class D(C):
...     pass
... 
>>> obj = D()
>>> obj.x = 'Stored in slots'
>>> obj.__dict__
{}
>>> obj.__dict__['x'] = 'stored in __dict__'
>>> obj.x
'Stored in slots'
```

Is this order of access (slots first) a documented behavior? or simply an implementation detail?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, the `__dict__` of an object is only consulted after data descriptors have been consulted. `__slots__` attributes are implemented as data descriptors.

See [Invoking descriptors](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#invoking-descriptors):

> For instance bindings, the precedence of descriptor invocation depends on the which descriptor methods are defined. A descriptor can define any combination of `__get__()`, `__set__()` and `__delete__()`. If it does not define `__get__()`, then accessing the attribute will return the descriptor object itself unless there is a value in the object’s instance dictionary. If the descriptor defines `__set__()` and/or `__delete__()`, it is a data descriptor; if it defines neither, it is a non-data descriptor. Normally, data descriptors define both `__get__()` and `__set__()`, while non-data descriptors have just the `__get__()` method. Data descriptors with `__set__()` and `__get__()` defined always override a redefinition in an instance dictionary. In contrast, non-data descriptors can be overridden by instances.

and from the same page, [section on slots](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#slots):

> `__slots__` are implemented at the class level by creating descriptors (Implementing Descriptors) for each variable name. As a result, class attributes cannot be used to set default values for instance variables defined by `__slots__`; otherwise, the class attribute would overwrite the descriptor assignment.

Comment: I believe this should also be quoted (from [Implementing Descriptors](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors)): "the descriptor must be in either the owner’s class dictionary or in the class dictionary for one of its parents".

Comment: @PavelAnossov: Not sure what that would add to understanding slots. The slot attributes are implemented as descriptors on the class, and data descriptors come before instance `__dict__` values. That is enough to document this behavior, is it not?

Comment: @PavelAnossov: Yes, sometimes people are confused as to where descriptors are looked up, but that is not at issue here.